# Figuring out programmatically if a Java class was patched?

Tags: java, android, security, digital-signature, checksum

Is it possible to figure it out programmatically, if anybody patched a class of a compiled code, especially in Android?
Example: My building (e.g. an .apk) contains a class PiracyCheck.class. Is it possible to run at compile time some kind of 'checksum' of that class (executed by another class)? I imagine that I get any value from it, let's say abcdefg. If anybody patches this class, the checksum would be suddenly 123456 instead of abcdefg. I verify the checksum on a backend server. If the checksum was correct, then proceed, if not, abort. or there any better solutions to achieve that?

(btw: If a cracker wants to repackage and resign the app, I would already be on the safe side, because I also check the signature, but I'm sure that anybody can bypass this check by decompiling and editing the bytecode itself, that means, a resign is not needed and the certificate won't change then).

Comment: the package signature would already be corrupt then ...just try it.

Comment: @MartinZeitler But how is it possible then, that patched apps are still working (and distributed on suspect sites). When I exec `context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures` doesn't it just read the data from META-INF/CERT.RSA inside the apk? So when I unpack the apk, change a bytecode, repack it (without resign), isn't the result stays the same then?

Comment: that might be the public key. however, each single file in the package should have been signed off with the private key. the mere difficulty is rather that one cannot check for the signature of the class, at least I have no clue how it could be accomplished. comparing that public key with a remote API might be the most common way. because then either it matches the private key - or that package is a) either corrupt or b) had been signed off with another key (as it might be the case with cracked versions). depending on connectivity for checks brings it's own problems with it.

Comment: the point is, that `classes.dex` is being signed, and not the contained classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some of those things.  But you can't put them together into a system that will prevent someone from running a "cracked" version of your code.

> Is it possible to run at compile time some kind of 'checksum' of that class (executed by another class)?

If is possible to generate a cryptographic checksum of a class at compile time, record on the server side, or in the ".apk", or both.

It is also possible to compute the such checksum on the client side.

What you can't do is force either the Android platform, or the hacked ".apk" to generate a **truthful** checksum:

- I don't think that the Android platform provides this functionality, and if it did, it could be subverted on a "rooted" device.
- Naturally, if someone went to the trouble of hacking your ".apk", they could subvert any "self checksumming" code in the ".apk" to deliver the original checksum rather than the checksum of the actual code.

Either way, your server will see the checksum that it is expecting, rather than a valid checksum of the actual code.  It will be fooled.

---

Basically, if you need to execute your code on a platform that is effectively in the control of the user, you cannot prevent the user from subverting your code.   The best you can hope for is to make it hard work for someone with the appropriate skills to do this.

Comment: You are right when you say that this is also not very truthful, because they could send the original checksum to my server, but I want to make it as difficult as possible for them. (I also added some other security implementations to my app, so I hope they'd loose interest earlier than later.)

Comment: Actually, it is not at all difficult to just send the wrong checksum.